# Convert Brainfuck to another language!

Tags: brainfuck

### The Task

Write the shortest program, that accepts script in brainfuck from `STDIN` (or equivalent) and outputs to `STDOUT` (or equivalent) a program written in the SAME language you're using.

For example, if you write in Java, with the input

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

The output can be

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, 5 bytes

```
+[,.]
```

This sentence circumvents the 30 char answer requirement.